# Scheduling Windows Service on specific day of the week

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I am using Windows Service for my program.
And I want to use my program on every Thursday 7:00AM.

```
                if (mode == "DAILY")
            {
                //Get the Scheduled Time from AppSettings.
                scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduledTime"]);
                if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                {
                    //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next day.
                    scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(7);
                }
            }
```

This is the code I am using now to execute my programs weekly. But is there any way I can use my programs on specific day of the week?(ex, Every Thursday 7:00AM)

Comment: Are you looking for? ``if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)`` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Rather than a windows service that runs constantly, perhaps you need a console application that is triggered by the windows task scheduler which would run the exe with any required parameters on the specified date/time.

Comment: This is what Scheduled Tasks are for, not services.